# Is 5" between 40" long propellers on an octocopter enough or is a greater distance needed

Tags: aerospace-engineering

These are carbon fiber propellers 40"long at the end of each arm

Answer (score 1):

Propellers' free stream into the blades is like a flared-out cone. but the output near the backside of the blades is concentrated and cylindrical.

.
[source](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/Wright/airplane/propth.html)

[image: proppeller flow]

That's one reason big drones use multiple propellers, so they don't take away from the in-flow of each other.

The lift rideshare is planning to introduce autonomous rideshare drones. They have tested the prototype and have received FAA approval to test fly it. As can be seen, the propellers are kept at a distance from each other.

[image: Lift Hexa Airplane]

Comment: Nice lesson. However, I think the OP is asking for the setup of multiple propellers on the same hub.

Comment: The NASA picture ignores the tangential (whirl) velocity in the prop output, which has no effect on the thrust but will definitely interfere with the airflow pattern if two props are close together.